# How can I drop off some elements from DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I just succesfully followed [Twitter Bootstrap 2 DataTables](http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2) tutorial.

Now I've DataTables in place like the [example](http://datatables.net/media/blog/bootstrap_2/) but I'd like to drop "records per page", "search", "Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries" and "pagination" elements, having just the table.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the dataTables constructor specify additional [options](http://datatables.net/ref), ie.:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bFilter": false, // Disable searching
    "bPaginate": false, // Disable pagination
    "bInfo": false    // Disable info texts
});
```

Comment: I get the following error :  "DataTables warning (table id = 'watch-list-table'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy"